# Python login system for a dice game

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, authentication

This is a finished login system where 2 players have to enter their username and password to proceed onto the game. The usernames and passwords are stored in a text file in this format`username: (username) password: (password)`. If one of the players enter their details in wrong it will loop it 3 times and if it is sill not correct they have to restart the code to try again.

```
import sys

counter = 0 
check_failed = True
while check_failed:
    print("Could player 1 enter their username and password")
    username1=input("Please enter your username ")
    password=input("Please enter your password ")
    with open("accountfile.txt","r") as username_finder:
        for line in username_finder:
            if ("username: " + username1 + " password: " + password) == line.strip():  
                print("you are logged in")
                check_failed = False
                check_failed = True
                while check_failed:
                    print("Could player 2 enter their username and password")
                    username2=input("Please enter your username ")
                    password=input("Please enter your password ")
                    with open("accountfile.txt","r") as username_finder:
                        for line in username_finder:
                            if ("username: " + username2 + " password: " + password) == line.strip():
                                print("you are logged in")
                                check_failed = False

                        else:
                            print("Sorry, this username or password does not exist please try again")
                            counter = counter + 1
                            if counter == 3:
                                print("----------------------------------------------------")
                                print("You have been locked out please restart to try again")
                                sys.exit()
        else:
            print("Sorry, this username or password does not exist please try again")
            counter = counter + 1
            if counter == 3:
                print("----------------------------------------------------")
                print("You have been locked out please restart to try again")
                sys.exit()
```

As I said this is a finished Login system and I just want suggestions on how I can improve this Login system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One guiding principle in software development is [Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Your code for player 1 and 2 are almost identical, so you should extract them into a `login` function:

```
import crypt

class AuthenticationError(Exception):
    pass

def encrypt(word, salt):
    # use some one-way hashing function here
    return crypt.crypt(word, salt)

def login(users, max_tries=3):
    for i in range(max_tries):
        username = input("Please enter your username ")
        password = input("Please enter your password ")
        if username in users and encrypt(password, username) == users[username]:
            print("You are logged in as", username)
            return username
        else:
            print(f"Login failed. You have {max_tries - i - 1} tries left.")
    raise AuthenticationError(f"You have been locked out please restart to try again.")
```

This uses a hashing function, like [@ChadG](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/163323/chad-g) suggested in [their answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/209084/98493), with a salt to prevent rainbow table attacks.

By raising an `Exception` (here a custom one, to give it a nice name), the execution of the program is automatically halted, so no need to explicitly do `sys.exit`.

This code assumes that you have read the users file before into a dictionary (only need to do it once!), something like this:

```
import re

def get_users(file_name):
    line_fmt = re.compile(r'username: (.*) password: (.*)')
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return dict(line_fmt.match(line.strip()).groups() for line in f)
```

Or, this slightly expanded version which ensures that the entries not conforming to the format are skipped (including any trailing newline):

```
def get_users(file_name):
    line_fmt = re.compile(r'username: (.*) password: (.*)')
    users = {}
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                name, password = line_fmt.match(line.strip()).groups()
                users[name] = password
            except AttributeError:
                print("Malformed line:", line)
        return users
```

Use it like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    registered_users = get_users("accountfile.txt")

    print("Could player 1 enter their username and password")
    player1 = login(registered_users)

    print("Could player 2 enter their username and password")
    player2 = login(registered_users)

    # start dice game
```

This uses a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script from another script.

Comment: the only thing is that this is project that I'm doing at school and their python don't have the module crypt and I can't install it but other than that everthing else you provided was very helpful!

Comment: @colkat406: That's why I put it into its own function, so you can easily swap out the implementation.

Comment: how would use the code you wrote in my code because I'm trying really hard to do it but just not working for me

Comment: @colkat406: Which part are you having trouble with? What does "not working" mean? It should work if you paste it all into one script and run it. Unless I made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: No its not you its me and I'm having trouble puting your code into mine

Comment: @colkat406: There is no need for any of your code (as far as you posted it in the question). Any further code you have should be under the guard below the player logins.

Comment: when I run the code you gave me i get this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/YT/Desktop/file.py", line 8, in <module>
    registered_users = get_users("accountfile.txt")
  File "C:/Users/YT/Desktop/file.py", line 6, in get_users
    return dict(line_fmt.match(line.strip()).groups() for line in f)
  File "C:/Users/YT/Desktop/file.py", line 6, in <genexpr>
    return dict(line_fmt.match(line.strip()).groups() for line in f)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`

Comment: @colkat406: That means one of the users has an empty password. Or your file has a trailing empty line (which is the same). I'll fix the code in a minute to skip this error.

Comment: I checked my file and it doesn't have an empty line

Comment: @colkat406: Well, it does mean that the matching did not succeed (and therefore getting the `groups` cannot work). So one of the lines does not conform to the format. Maybe a space is missing somewhere? There must be one on each side of the username and one before the password.

Comment: The format inside the file looks like this `username: john password: j123` and its like that for all of the users

Comment: @colkat406: Can you try with the (edited) extended version of `get_users`? It should print the offending line.

Comment: When I run the code nothing comes up

Comment: @colkat406: So it works? either it runs without printing "Malformed line.", it prints the offending line(s) or it dies with another error. Which one is it?

Comment: I ran the code to find the offending line but nothing came up but when i try the other code you gave me i still get the same error also in this part of the code `def get_users(file_name)` am i suppose to put the actual file name there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86675/discussion-between-graipher-and-colkat406).

Comment: lets go to the chat again

Comment: Please could we go back to the chat I sent a screenshot of the error I keep on getting maybe that will help

Comment: This is a screenshot of the error i keep on getting ibb.co/k4KCHfP

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to set `check_failed` to `False` before you set it to `True`; you can remove that line. And passwords should never be stored in plain text: you should store the hashed value, then hash what the user enters and compare it to what you have stored.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this also when ever player 1 and player 2 enter their details correctly it print "you are logged  in" but it also prints "Sorry, this username or password does not exist please try again" twice for some reason afterwards. do you think you can help?

Comment: That can be printed in two places, change one of them slightly so you know which case is printing it. That should help narrow down the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by change one of them slightly?

Comment: You have two places in you code with this line print("Sorry, this username or password does not exist please try again")   You dont know which one of them is actually printing that line.   So change one to print("SORRY, this username or password does not exist please try again"). This way you know which one is causing your problem, and you can then trace why its happening.

Comment: Both lines are being printed so I don't know what the promblem could be

Comment: Its because you are checking every line for a match, and its not you are printing that.   So its on the line with user1 information, you code checks that against the info entered by user2, which of course will not match.  You need to first scan the file for a matching user name, and THEN compare the password before you say its wrong.    So you actually have three options.logged in,UserName not found, or password doesnt match.

Comment: You are also opening the file twice which isnt needed.   You should probably open the file, parse the user names and passwords into a dict and then start asking the users for their information.

Comment: is it possible for you to write the code out correctly because I have tried to correct it and I'm having no luck so it would be really helpful if you could do it for me :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86667/discussion-between-colkat406-and-chad-g).

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written for player two is just the same for player one as they both perform the same end result(log in a player). So instead I would recommend you create a function in which logs in a player and then just use that function twice instead of having to type out the whole code twice. This makes it much simpler and easier.

Also as a side note you could store the users in a dictionary:

```
users = {
    'Joe': 'juk725',
    'Mat': 'axr3',
    'Th3_j0k3r': 'bl4z3',
    'ag4r-j3lly': 'Micr0b3'
}
```

--> and then create a pickle file(on a separate program) where these users are stored:

```
import pickle

users = {
    'Joe': 'juk725',
    'Mat': 'axr3',
    'Th3_j0k3r': 'bl4z3',
    'ag4r-j3lly': 'Micr0b3'
}

with open('users.pickle', 'wb') as afile:
    # Pickle the 'data' dictionary using the highest protocol available.
    pickle.dump(users, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

--> then create a definition of users in you login system:

```
with open('users.pickle', 'rb') as a_file:
    users = pickle.load(a_file)
```

This addition will allow you to give new users access to signup / register as well as providing an easy way to store users.

[ ocr gcse comp science right ;) ]

```
login_or_signup = input('do you want to login or signup? ')

# sign up (creating new account)
if login_or_signup.lower() == "signup":

    create_username = input("enter a new username: ")
    create_password = input("enter a new password (Your password cannot be the same as your username !!!!!!!): ")

    if create_password in users:
        create_password = input("password taken re-enter: ")

    users[create_username] = create_password
```

Comment: do i put the users in a seperate python promgram

Comment: yep  so open a new program and type the second block of code in

Comment: its saying that in the second block of code that ' f ' is not defined

Comment: and the first one at the beginning of your login system and the last at the end of your login system

Comment: over my original code right

Comment: Im not to sure what you mean so could you show me please

Comment: k see what ive done :https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/209733/dice-game-login-system

Comment: How do I add users to the pickle file without me typing them in manually

Comment: check the answer above at the very bottom